# Using the same logout.php page for two different types clients

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple website that lets the admins and users log in. There credentials are saved onto a mysql server in 2 separate tables. 1 for user, 1 for admin.

They both of different login pages, user has userlogin.php and admin has adminlogin.php

What i want is, when they are both done with accessing the site, i want them to click logout and through session variables, use just the one logout.php and redirect them to their respective login pages.

So if the user logs out, they should be redirected to userlogin.php and if admin logs out, they should be redirected to adminlogin.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();

unset($_SESSION["userid"]);  
header("Location: userlogin.php");


unset($_SESSION["adminid"]);  
header("Location: adminlogin.php");

?>
```

This is what i have so far.

Comment: So check which variable is set and act accordingly. By the way, why do you have 2 login pages? One is enough and at the backend you check the logged-in user's permissions.

Comment: but how can i add an if statement, what will be the values, i cant just say if($_SESSION=$_SESSION['userid']){...} @jeroen

Comment: In my oponion you're doing the actual structure incorrectly. You should store both normal users and admins in same table. And then define roles (admin, normal user) for each row. In this way you don't create several function when handling users. Depending on the role sett you can do different things.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
{
  unset($_SESSION["userid"]);  
  header("Location: userlogin.php");
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION["adminid"]))
{
  unset($_SESSION["adminid"]);  
  header("Location: adminlogin.php");
}
die();
```

Comment: Nope it's too simple for an explanation :) Its self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Use session_destroy()

**logout.php**

```
<?php    
    session_start();                
    if(isset($_SESSION["adminid"]))
    {
      unset($_SESSION["adminid"]); 
      session_destroy(); 
      header("Location: adminlogin.php");
    }
    else
    {
     unset($_SESSION["userid"]);  
     session_destroy(); 
     header("Location: userlogin.php");

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: There's no point unsetting variables if you use session_destroy() afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header ('Location: ' . (isset($_SESSION['adminid']) ? 'adminlogin.php' : 'userlogin.php'));
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Since some people asked for an explanation, this code first starts the session with `session_start();`.

After that, it sets the location header to be sent to the client. The code checks if the adminid is set, if so, we'll redirect to adminlogin.php. If not, we'll just redirect to userlogin.php.

Then, the code sets the `$_SESSION` to `array();` (basically just empties it) so that all the previously set data is gone.

Finally, the session is destroyed and the client will get redirected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer some? SO exists to teach, not just answer questions

Comment: I was assuming the OP and anyone else looking for an answer would have a basic understanding of PHP. Edited my answer for those that don't know PHP well enough to understand it.